# How to extract arguments from url that are separated with # in Scala Play

Tags: scala, http, playframework, google-oauth, fragment-identifier

I'm implementing the offline Google OAuth flow in Scala Play.

The user clicks on the dialogue "yes I want this application to access the following data of my Google account...". After the user has clicked Ok, the Google server sends a token to my server.
A sample response looks like this (URL of my browser window):

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com/storeauthcode#code=123&login_hint=abc&client_id[crypticId].apps.googleusercontent.com&prompt=consent

How do I extract the the 123 substring (which is my access token) from the current url in the current browser window?:

```
def storeAuthCode = Action { request =>

    //save token
    //confirm login of user now
  }
```

Extracting data like query params does of course not work.

```
request.path
```

returns

```
/storeauthcode
```

but not the String with the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of the URL after the `#` is known as the *[fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)*.  The fragment identifier is not sent to the server by the browser:

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server — of course the server typically helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a web resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

If it is necessary, you could parse out the fragment on the client side and then send it as part of the request body or query string instead.

Comment: Thanks for this very good and incredibly fast answer! No the thing is, I cannot parse the url on the client side, because when you login with Google, a new window opens and this window is a Google website (the Google OAuth dialogue), so I can't parse it here. So the solution is to advise the Google server to send the token to my (third party) website first. And then the token is sent to my server via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Another relevant answer to this question is the OAuth2 flow being used by @slashburn is incorrect for the use case.  Google refers to this flow as the "[OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)". This flow is intended for use by client side only browser apps that can read the fragment. The flow is initiated when the browser client requests the response_type of "token".

```html
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Fcallback&
response_type=token&
client_id=client_id
```

The appropriate flow to use instead of the client flow is "[OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)". This flow is intended for web applications that use a web server to interact with google apis. Instead of the value of "token" for the response_type, the value is "code".

```html
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Fcallback&
response_type=code&
client_id=client_id
```

This flow is a little more complicated because the OAuth2 server will send back a temporary code.  The server then POSTs to the OAuth2 server directly with the temporary code to get the token back using a url and body that looks like this.

```html
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

The reason why server and client applications use different flows is to prevent the transmission of the access code in the clear over the wire. For the client flow, the fragment stays completely local to the browser and so there is nothing for an attacker to sniff. For the server flow,  only a one time code can be seen by an attacker. The one time code is useless without the server's secret. The server POSTs the code and secret in its body to get a response from server and both parts of the communication are encrypted by the HTTPS protocol.